# Hex code issue with Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app where I am trying to add gradient to button dynamically by coding. The 6 digit hex code works if I apply the gradient in the xml ,statically ; but doesn't work when I try to change the gradient from java. In this case 8 bit hex code works.
Please help me solve this issue.

```
public void setGradient(btnGradientStartColor,btnGradientEndColor,buttonUnderAction) {

    int colors[] = { btnGradientStartColor, btnGradientEndColor };
    for(int x:colors){
        System.out.println("value in colors[]:"+x);
    }
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR, colors);
    btnUnderAction.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);

}
```

I am passing hex color codes and button id to this method . Here if I pass 6 digit hex code it doesn't work but 8 digit hex code works.
      e.g.  0xff255779 and 0xffa6c0cd works but 0x30196E and 0x3498db doesn't work.

Is there any way to convert 6 digit hex code to 8 digit codes , or can I get my code work with the 6 digit codes !!!!

Comment: Not enough information to help you.

Comment: Add some relevant code.

Comment: Is the information I have edited being able to help you understand my problem???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 2 digits (ff) are alpha. ff means fully opaque, 00 means fully transparent. 
In xml if you use #00ff00, it is modified to ff00ff00 (adding the leading ff automatically).
In code, if you have 00ff00 it is translated to 0000ff00, so fully transparent.
If you have a code in hex do

```
color = color | 0xff000000;
```

to make it fully opaque